# Error while trying to import a CSV file into Hive

Tags: csv, hive, bigdata

I tried to import my [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) data into [Hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hive).

My query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE student(Stud_name String,dept String,year String)
  > ROW FORMAT serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
  > with serdeproperties (
  >    "separatorChar" = ","
  > )
  > STORED AS TEXTFILE
  > LOCATION '/home/codewarrior/Desktop/csv';
```

But it gives this error:

[image: Error Message]

And it quits from Hive... How can I fix it?

Comment: The code you put at the beginning is actually different from the one you show on the screenshot - different table name, different fields, and an escapeChar serde parameter.  Could you copy and paste the *exact* code that you're using so we can have a look at exactly what you're running ?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35955055/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code instead:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE student(Stud_name String,dept String,year String) 
ROW FORMAT AS DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED by ',' location '/home/codewarrior/Desktop/csv';
```